# dismissViewController completion:, need to load function, can't get it to work

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Calling Code here within `GameListViewController`:

```
[self presentViewController:[[StartNewGameViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"StartNewGameViewController" bundle:nil] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Callback Code here within StartNewGameViewController:

```
[(id)self.parentViewController showSetup:m_tableID];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [GLVC showSetup:m_tableID];
}];
```

Also have tried:

```
[(id)self.GLVC showSetup:m_tableID];
```

Tried three different methods above here.  The first method has **no error**, bottom method says show Setup has no known class method, third method also no error.  First and third have no errors, but are not working.

`.h` of `StartNewGameController`

```
#import "GamelistViewController.h"
@property (nonatomic, assign) GamelistViewController *GLVC;
```

And I synthesize **GLVC** on the top of the `.m`

"showSetup" is a method that works just fine while called from `GameListViewController` and is declared in `GameListViewController.h` like so:

```
-(void)showSetup:(int)tableID;
```

I've seen some other stack overflow questions related to this one, but none of them have resolved my issue.

Comment: change To @property (nonatomic, assign) GamelistViewController *GLVC; and [GLVC showSetup:m_tableID];

Comment: Removes the error, functionality not working quite yet though.

Comment: Didn't think I needed to, since GLVC already exists where I came from

Comment: Try NSLog(@"@%",GLVC). I think you will get null.

Comment: yea, showed up NULL.  Not sure how to allocate it if I'm dismissing the view controller as opposed to presenting a new one though.

Comment: That is problem there is nothing in GLVC how can it do anything?

Comment: Put reference of created object of that class.

Comment: I don't have that at all, to be honest I'm still new to this, I don't even understand what that means :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [(id)self.parentViewController showSetup:m_tableID];

works because the reference to `parentViewController` is automatically configured for you.

> [GLVC showSetup:m_tableID];

should be `_GLVC` or, preferably `self.GLVC` and doesn't work because you never set the reference before you present the view controller. (previously it didn't work because you were using a class name, expecting it to be an instance variable name, due to bad naming, but it wasn't).

> [(id)self.GLVC showSetup:m_tableID];

Is really the same as the above (in your new edited code).

The solution is to set `GLVC` on the created view controller before you call `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

```
StartNewGameViewController *svc = [[StartNewGameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartNewGameViewController" bundle:nil];
svc.GLVC = self;

[self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the stuff i guess. `presentingViewController` will automatically set it for you while presenting the controller.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [(id)self.presentingViewController showSetup:m_tableID];
}];
```

Comment: While it might work, it isn't nice. What if another controller presents this view in the future -> exception... You could use `respondsToSelector:` to protect against that, but still not nice